# Cannot set string on variable in c#

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am debugging a payment error in a team project. I am still very new to c#.  So if I am missing some simple logic please feel free to let me know.

The problem I am having is that I have a Sitecore value that is not getting set to the a property in the code.  It is leaving me with an **empty string**

I have the following variable

```
var paymentTokenResponse = new PaymentToken();
```

This is set as so

```
paymentTokenResponse.ErrorMessage = SitecoreApplicationLogic.GetFieldValue(INVALID_CC_ERROR_MSG, ResourceGUIDs.ReviewAndPay)
```

The ErrorMessage property is set as a string  like so

```
 public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
```

What is puzzling me in the debugger's watch I am getting

```
SitecoreApplicationLogic.GetFieldValue(INVALID_CC_ERROR_MSG, ResourceGUIDs.ReviewAndPay)
```

To return the string   **"You are paying with an invalid credit card**

But as I step over the property I see

```
paymentTokenResponse.ErrorMessage = " ".
```

Comment: Are you trying to convince us that C# is buggy and auto properties do not work?

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong in your diagnosis of the problem.  If the right side of an assignment has a given value, then after the assignment operation the left side will have that value.  If that didn't work consistently, nothing would.

Comment: No.  I just do not see how this value isn't getting attached.

Comment: are you looking at the value when the debugger is specifically on that line? have you checked what the value is when you go 1 line past `paymentTokenResponse.ErrorMessage = SitecoreApplicationLogic.GetFieldValue(INVALID_CC_ERROR_MSG, ResourceGUIDs.ReviewAndPay)`?

Comment: @David I know.  I feel I am missing something straight forward.  I will try to get more code in the question. But right now my watch see's a string and it is not getting assigned.  It would make sense if it was getting assigned then changed.

Comment: Even though my sitecore value returns as a string.  I had to add SitecoreApplicationLogic.GetFieldValue(INVALID_CC_ERROR_MSG, ResourceGUIDs.ReviewAndPay).ToString().   Now it works!   If I can explain why I need .ToString on a string to myself I will put it as the answer.